# Stealing things which I put back where I steal it

Tags: halal-haram

I stole from my younger roommate. I stole her unused notebooks but I didn't steal high value items from her. I only get that because she was not using it and might be put to waste after. I don't know what to do. She was stealing back what's her mine from my bag and I didn't bother to talk to her about that matter.

Comment: To make this answerable you should consider re-reading yoru post and put the corerct possessive determiner in the correct place. As is it is unclear what you mean.